# CircleButton LongClickListener not triggered

Tags: java, android, button, onlongclicklistener

I use a CircleButton from the lib MaterialWidget. In my Fragment I try to use a LongClickListener on this component, but it is not working. A ClickListener is working but not the long one.

Lib : https://github.com/keithellis/MaterialWidget/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/material/widget/CircleButton.java

It is working with a standard button.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_home, container, false);

    rootView.findViewById(R.id.cb_startPhotoe).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isLongClickReleased) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NavigationActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("fake", 1);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });

    rootView.findViewById(R.id.cb_startPhotoe).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            isLongClickReleased = false;
            displayMenu(rootView);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

When I see the code of the lib, nothing special appear to me.
In debug mode, it the listener is not triggered
Even if I comment the OnClickListener, nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use the particular library but I read the code and found that in the `onTouchEvent` method, `performClick()` is called once in MOTION_UP case block. This is what triggers your OnClickListener. Therefore for long click, you need to insert in that method `performLongClick()` that suits your needs.

Here's my idea to do long click. It's pretty simple but you need to customize that CircleButton class. So add a class variable say `long tsDown;`

```
private long tsDown;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             ...
             tsDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
             break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            ...
            if (!mMoveOutside) {
                long tsUp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (tsUp - tsDown < 1000){
                  // if press duration is below 1s                       
                  performClick();
                }else{
                  performLongClick();
                }  
            }
            break;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I missed it ! What if I have the 2 events to handle for 2 different  actions ? Should a reimplement short/long click behavior ?

Comment: Well I've got a sketchy idea how to incorporate both kinds of clicks. I'll just edit my answer